# php extract numbers and variables in math function

Tags: php, math, numbers, extract

I have a math function, for example:

```
string = "3x+6.5y-23z"
```

I need to extract the function and get `x`, `y`, `z`; give value `x = 6`, `y = 7`, `z = 8`; and solve.

Comment: what you have tried? StackOverflow is not for provide full program... Try something on your own..

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
<?php 
  $x = 6;
  $y = 7;
  $z = 8;

 echo  $string = 3*$x+6.5*$y-23*$z;
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case I can't do it, the mentioned string comes from form, the user must type math function in form and get the answer.